# how can i send an api call from the supreme function to another component called product to change a mock data called cart: true and display in cart

Tags: reactjs

```
function Supreme(){

    return (
      <div>
        <Meniu />
        <Informatii />
        <h1 className="title">Supreme</h1>
        <Product myObj={supremeData}/>
        <div className="numar">
          <p >{supremeData.length} Products</p>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
}

function Product (props) {
    
    const Lista = [...props.myObj]
    return (
        <div className="product-list">
                        {Lista.map((produse)=>{
                            return(
                                <div className="produse" key={produse.id}>
                                <img src={produse.image} />
                                <h1>{produse.name}</h1>
                                <h2>{produse.price}</h2>
                                <button className="button-product">ADD TO CART</button>
                                </div>              
                            )

                        })}
                     
        </div>
    )
}
```

How can I send an API call from the supreme function to another component called product to change mock data called cart: true and display it in cart?

Answer (score 0):

1- Define a method for handling api call in supreme component.
2- Pass it to Product component same as you did for "myObj" prop.
3- Call defined method when required event happened in product component.(for example: componentDidMount or onclcik)

```
function Supreme(){
  cosnt [card , setCard]=useState({})
  const method = (p)=>{
  axious.post(p).then(res=> setCard(res)}}
return (
 <div>
<Meniu />
<Informatii />
<h1 className="title">Supreme</h1>
<Product myObj={supremeData} apiCall={method}/>
<div className="numar">
  <p >{supremeData.length} Products</p>
</div>
<Footer /></div>);}
```

And Product Component

```
 function Product (props) {
  const Lista = [...props.myObj]
  return (
   <div className="product-list">
    {Lista.map((produse)=>{
   return(
    <div className="produse" key={produse.id}>
    <img src={produse.image} />
    <h1>{produse.name}</h1>
    <h2>{produse.price}</h2>
    <button onclick={()=>props.apiCall()}
        className="button-product">ADD TO CART</button>
        </div>
         )

              })}
               </div>
                      )
                         }
```

Comment: cant i just use setState in product?

Comment: i used setstate and i get the cart : true but i didnt change in mock data and i dont get the id too

Comment: You can use setState directly in the component that state defined  or define a mthod that using setState and pass it to another component to call as you need. For your case  I need more information . please include more lines of your code in the question .

Comment: i`ve managed to do it using setstate but now it re-renders in infinite loop and use effect is not working

Comment: const method = (p)=>{
  axious.post(p).then(res=> setCard(res)}} is not working